# Powershell populate word table from an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, ms-word

I have a PS script that will import a csv into several arrays and I need it to populate a table in word.  I am able to get the data into the arrays, and create a table with headers and the correct number of rows, but cannot get the data from the arrays into the table. Doing lots of google searches led me to the following code.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sample of My_File.txt
Number of rows will vary, but the header row is always there.

component,id,iType,

VCT,AD-1234,Story,

VCT,Ad-4567,DR,

```
$component = @()
$id = @()
$iType =@()
$vFile = Import-CSV ("H:\My_file.txt")
$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"

$vFile | ForEach-Object {
$component += $_.components
$id += $_.id
$iType +=_.iType
}

$template = $word.Documents.Open ("H:\Test.docx")

$template = $word.Document.Add()
$word.Visible = $True
$Number_rows = ($vFile.count +1)
$Number_cols = 3

$range = $template.range()
$template.Tables.add($range, $Number_rows, $Number_cols) | out-null

$table = $template.Tables.Item(1)
$table.cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Component"
$table.cell(1,2).Range.Text = "ID"
$table.cell(1,3).Range.text = "Type"

for ($i=0; $i -lt; $vFile.count+2, $i++){
$table.cell(($i+2),1).Range.Text = $component[$i].components
$table.cell(($i+2),2).Range.Text = $id[$i].id
$table.cell(($i+2),3).Range.Text = $iType[$i].iType
}

$Table.Style = "Medium Shading 1 - Accent 1"
$template.SaveAs("H:\New_Doc.docx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't separate the rows in the parsed CSV object array into three arrays, but leave the collection as-is and use the data to fill the table using the properties of that object array directly.

I took the liberty of renaming your variable `$vFile` into `$data` as to me at least this is more descriptive of what is in there.

Try

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path "H:\My_file.txt"
$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$word.Visible = $True

$template = $word.Documents.Open("H:\Test.docx")
$Number_rows = $data.Count +1  # +1 for the header
$Number_cols = 3

$range = $template.Range()
[void]$template.Tables.Add($range, $Number_rows, $Number_cols)

$table = $template.Tables.Item(1)
$table.Style = "Medium Shading 1 - Accent 1"

# write the headers
$table.cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Component"
$table.cell(1,2).Range.Text = "ID"
$table.cell(1,3).Range.text = "Type"

# next, add the data rows
for ($i=0; $i -lt $data.Count; $i++){
    $table.cell(($i+2),1).Range.Text = $data[$i].component
    $table.cell(($i+2),2).Range.Text = $data[$i].id
    $table.cell(($i+2),3).Range.Text = $data[$i].iType
}

$template.SaveAs("H:\New_Doc.docx")
```

---

When done, do not forget to close the document, quit word and clean up the used COM objects:

```
$template.Close()
$word.Quit()

$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($template)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thanks...But I don't understand what [void] is.  I changed my code to exactly this an dit still doesn't work.  I get the header row, but no data in the table.

Comment: @ErikT `[void]` simply means it should swallow the output from that command, same as `$null =` or piping to `Out-Null` would do. If you don't get any data, then I suspect your `H:\My_file.txt` input file is not a proper CSV file, OR the fields in there are not delimited by a comma, but some other character (maybe `;` or a TAB?) Please, open that file in notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines and add that to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71663199/edit) as text, so I can see what we are importing.

Comment: I added the [void] as you suggested, but now I get  the following (along with no data in the table):  "System.Management.Automation.ComInterop.BoundDispEvent

OverloadDefinitions
---------------------
void Quit[ref] System.Object SaveChanges, [ref] System.Object OriginalFormat.......

Comment: @ErikT No, i only used [void] on the `.Add()` method to discard its output. From what you show of the input file, there is no property `iType`, but its name is `issuetype`. Also, `components` in reality is called `component`. If you do not use the header names exactly you won't get output of course

Comment: I used the header names as they are in the file...I changed my code names for brevity.  So, I can print out {$data} and all the data is there.  I even added {$data[$i].component} and it printed out exactly what I would expect.  So I thought, change the cell reference in the line 
{Tables.Cell(($i+2).Range.Text = $data[$i].component} to {Tables.Cell(2,1).Range.Text = $data[$i].component} but the cell is still blank

Comment: @ErikT Sorry, there was a small typo in there: `for ($i=0; $i -lt $data.Count, $i++)` should have been `for ($i=0; $i -lt $data.Count; $i++)` (note the semi-colon instead of comma). Also I left in the line `$template = $word.Document.Add()` but erased that now as it only creates errors. Using your input csv as example this works for me in Word 2016, although my Dutch version doesn't understand the style in English, but that should not be a problem on your side.

Comment: Thanks for all this.  Turned out the issue was something hung up in the PS window.  After I cycled the window, everything worked great.